# Edit onclick url in button

Tags: javascript, button, onclick, tampermonkey

I'm trying to edit the url in a button onclick event. Below is the source of the button and the text I'd like to strip from the onclick portion. The end goal is to have a Tampermonkey script that allows me to easily download stp files without manually editing a link after clicking it.

Remove

```
"fusion360://command=insert&file=" +
```

From

```
<button type='button' class="event btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" onclick='window.location.href = "fusion360://command=insert&file=" + encodeURIComponent("https://assets.sas-automation.com/cad/SWM%203.stp");' data-category="Product Sidebar Right" data-action="Button Click" data-label="Opened CAD File in Fusion" aria-label="button">Open in Fusion360</button>
```

Comment: for better maintence and readability, why you don't remove the script from the inline and create a isolated function to do what you need? It will let you with many more options

Comment: The button code in my question is part of a website's source code not something I'm creating. Maybe I didn't explain it clearly enough but I am trying to modify the link on a website with a userscript in Tampermonkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this, here is one that came to my mind:

1. Use a getElementsByClassName (or any other selector function) to grab the button
2. Save the `onclick` attribute value (which is of text type) to a variable
3. Find the given substring and replace it with an empty string
4. Save the result back to the button's `onclick` attribute.

NOTE: your solution has a gotcha: in order to get a proper redirect on button click, you have to remove the method `encodeURIComponent` since the url appears to be encoded already.

And you should be good to go. You can play with the snippet.

```js
var button = document.getElementsByClassName('event btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block')[0];
var onClick = button.getAttribute('onclick')
.replace(/"fusion360:\/\/command=insert&file="\s*\+\s/, '')
.replace('encodeURIComponent(', '')
.replace(');', '');
button.setAttribute('onclick', onClick);
```

```html
<button type='button' class="event btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" onclick='window.location.href = "fusion360://command=insert&file=" + encodeURIComponent("https://assets.sas-automation.com/cad/SWM%203.stp");'
  data-category="Product Sidebar Right" data-action="Button Click" data-label="Opened CAD File in Fusion" aria-label="button">Open in Fusion360</button>
```